# Moment.js Convert Local time to UTC time does work

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to use Moment.js to convert a local time to UTC equivalent. I believe that I have the correct method in place, but it does not alter the time.

I'm in Sydney Australian +11 and expect the UTC time to be 11 hours earlier.

Internally on the moment object the isUTC flag changes from false to true, but the time does NOT shift, am I meant to use a different technique for this.

How do I actually get the current UTC date out of this object

Before Conversion

```
var val = '18/03/2015';
var selectedDate = moment(val, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

[image: Before Conversion]

After Conversion

```
var a = selectedDate.utc()
```

[image: After Conversion]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert from GMT/UTC to local time and back using momentjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070296/how-to-convert-from-gmt-utc-to-local-time-and-back-using-momentjs)

Answer (score 23):

I just tried this code and it seems like I get the correct UTC time. I guess I just want to confirm that what I am doing is correct way to access the UTC time from moment.js

```
a.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ")
```

[image: "2015-03-18 04:19:46+00:00"]

I found that my usage pattern of in my application was incorrect

```
selectedDate.utc().format(fullFormat)
```

It should have been

```
moment.utc(selectedDate).format(fullFormat)
```

Comment: That last code snippet is correct. Take a look at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/ . In order to get into utc mode, you should create a new moment. Though in my own testing, I seem to be able to call `.utc()` on an existing moment successfully, so who knows.

Comment: not `moment().utc(...`, but `moment.utc(...`, I guess :)

Comment: @medik is right, you should use `moment.utc(datetime).format(MOMENT_UTC_DATE_TIME_FORMAT)`

Comment: if selectedDate be a timestamp in milisecond, it dos not work. why?

Answer (score 11):

This works

```
moment(date_to_convert).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is old, but I also faced it. It may be useful to someone:

Using the method of utcOffset() to calculate the UTC time:

```
selectedDate = (moment(selectedDate).add(-(moment().utcOffset()), 'm'));
```

And explicitly specify UTC:

```
selectedDate = moment.parseZone(selectedDate).utc().format();
```

Comment: I think I had the reverse problem... dates, in JSON, were utc but interpreted as local, so I had to add the utc offset.  One thing though, I think you really want to use the selectedDate to determine the offset as it will change... this was my code:  const correctedDateTime = m.add((moment(utcDate).utcOffset()), 'm');

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it using `moment-timezone`

```
moment.tz(localDate, localTimeZone).utc()
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me !!

```
selectedDate = moment(selectedDate).add(moment(selectedDate).utcOffset(), 'm').utc().format()
```

Comment: This does not work if the offset needs to be subtracted.

Comment: It does work for the subtraction cases as the utcOffset returns a negative value for such cases

Answer (score 2):

Create a local moment object from you local time and convert it to UTC then format it, then create a new UTC moment from that formatted UTC string

```js
var localDateString = '24/04/2019';
var localDateStringFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

var utcMoment = moment.utc(moment(localDateString, localDateStringFormat ).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ'))

console.log(utcMoment);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

After few frustrating hours, I found what was the problem

Short Answer: To convert time to utc, we need to use `format()`

Long Answer: Take the example

`moment.utc(1559586600000).format('LLL')`

.utc sets the isUTC flag to true.

When logging the date, the `d` key always shows the time in local timezone. (Which makes us believe its not working properly - as shown in your screenshot)

But we need to use .format to get the date/time in UTC format.

The above code returns `June 3, 2019 6:30 PM` which is the correct UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const dateTime='2020-12-21'
const timezone='America/Anchorage'
const dateTimeInUtc = moment(dateTime).tz(timezone).utc().format();
console.log('dateTimeInUtc',dateTimeInUtc);
```

Answer (score 0):

After few frustrating hours, I found what was the problem

Short Answer: To convert time to utc, we need to use format()

Long Answer: Take the example

moment.utc(1559586600000).format('LLL')

.utc sets the isUTC flag to true.

When logging the date, the d key always shows the time in local timezone. (Which makes us believe its not working properly - as shown in your screenshot)

But we need to use .format to get the date/time in UTC format.

The above code returns June 3, 2019 6:30 PM which is the correct UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

```html
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const dateTime='2020-12-21'
const timezone='America/Anchorage'
const dateTimeInUtc = moment(dateTime).tz(timezone).utc().format();
console.log('dateTimeInUtc',dateTimeInUtc);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should probably merge this with your earlier answer, or otherwise explain how the two different answers relate to each other.