# How to convert from GMT/UTC to local time and back using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following string:

"December 25, 2018 01:02:20"

I intend this to be GMT/UTC Using moment.js, how do I convert this to local time and back to UTC?

When I do:

```
moment(myDateString).local()
```

Then later to try to convert back:

```
moment(myDateStrig).utc()
```

They both yield different results. How do I make it so that I can convert the time I have from UTC to local, then back to UTC?

Note:
When I try the `.utc()` function on the string `"December 25, 2018 01:02:20"` I get a different time. When I do a `.local()` on the utc converted moment, I get a different date that is not my original date of `"December 25, 2018 01:02:20"`.

Please show an example if you can as I it looks like I have 3 different dates.

Comment: "December 25, 2018 01:02:20" does not have a time zone, so it will be interpreted as a local time. Then, calling `utc()` will convert it to UTC time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to UTC using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299950/convert-date-to-utc-using-moment-js)

Comment: This is covered in [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)...

Comment: I have looked at those, and they don't seem to match my problem. PLease note the date string I am working with..."December 25, 2018 01:02:20". When I do the utc() it changes it to something else. When I use .local() it does not match "December 25, 2018 01:02:20"

Comment: you should look for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321495/how-to-convert-from-utc-to-local-time-in-moment-js/66152470#66152470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input represent UTC time, you have to use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) (as suggested by others in the comments):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

Moreover, since your input string is not in a format recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) (ISO 8601 or RFC 2822), you have to pass format parameter as second argument of `moment.utc`, see [String + Format parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) section of the docs.

Here a code sample:

```js
var input = "December 25, 2018 01:02:20";
var fmt = 'MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm:ss';
var m = moment.utc(input, fmt);
console.log(m.local().format(fmt));
console.log(m.utc().format(fmt));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to interpret a string such as "December 25, 2018 01:02:20" which does not have a time zone on it, you can call `moment()` on it, which will interpret it as local time, or you can call [`moment.utc()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) on it, which will interpret it as UTC time.

Try this:

```
const myUtcMoment = moment.utc(myDateString)
```

This should result in a `Moment` object that represents 01:02:20 AM on December 25, 2018 in the UTC time zone.

In order to convert that `Moment` to local time, you can do this:

```
const myLocalMoment = myUtcMoment.local()
```

And to convert it back, you can call `myLocalMoment.utc()`.

By the way, with this date format, it is not really clear whether this is 24-hour time or not. The Moment.js docs [recommend specifying a format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) in order to alleviate ambiguity.

Comment: The problem is when I do a .format() on myUtcMoment and myLocalMoment to make it look like the original, I can't get it to look like this: ""December 25, 2018 01:02:20" It looks like it is at a different date/time!

Comment: @Rolando Can you give an example of what it looks like instead?