# Moment Js from UTC time

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, utc

I want to calculate relative time to UTC time. My local time is +2.

I was trying many combinations...
For example

```js
const endDate = new Date("08 Jun 2018") // tomorrow's date, I am expecting the time is 00:00:00
const utcDateTime = new Date(moment.utc().format());
const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

console.log(moment(endDate).fromNow()) // example for Poland(+2) it is 12, but I want to UTC(0), so it is should be 14
console.log(moment(endDate).from(utcDateTime)) // the same
console.log(moment(endDate.toUTCString()).from(utcDateTime)) // the same
console.log(moment(moment(endDate).utc().format(format), format).fromNow()) // I do not why, but it is 10, not 14
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js
"></script>
```

And every time I am getting relative time, which is correct for my local time. UTC should be 2 hours bigger.

I do not know how I should do that...

Can some help me?

Thank you!

EDIT

Based on @31piy suggestion, I've tried something like this.

```js
const endDate = new Date("08 Jun 2018") // tomorrow's date, I am expecting the time is 00:00:00
const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

console.log(moment(endDate).from(moment(moment.utc().format(format), format)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js
"></script>
```

And it is working for me, but... How can I do that more clearly? Is it possible?

EDIT2

It was my fault... I was passing a date ("08 June 2018"), which was in UTC timezone, to Date constructor, but I did not specify that is UTC - so in fact, endDate should be equal to `"08 June 2018 02:00:00"`, not `"08 Jun 2018 00:00:00"`. I fixed that and very clear `moment(endDate).fromNow(true)` is working for me.

Thanks for helping me with that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js Convert Local time to UTC time does work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114824/moment-js-convert-local-time-to-utc-time-does-work)

Comment: Answers from this topic did not help me... In fact, I think that problem is that, I do not want to change "endDate", but I want to change value of "now". It should be UTC (local-2, for me), but it is calculating relative time from local. But, from UTC date it is also not working, and I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is a bit tricky. You need to format a UTC time without the timezone info, and then parse it using moment again before calling `fromNow()` on it:

```js
const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
console.log(moment(moment.utc().format(format), format).fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js
"></script>
```

Comment: I've updated my question. I was trying your suggestion, but after that, I've got (local+2) time, not (local-2, which should be UTC) time

Comment: I've updated my question again. based on your suggestion I've done something, which is working... But can I do that more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault... I was passing a date ("08 June 2018"), which was in UTC timezone, to Date constructor, but I did not specify that is UTC - so in fact, endDate should be equal to `"08 June 2018 02:00:00"`, not `"08 Jun 2018 00:00:00"`. I fixed that and very clear `moment(endDate).fromNow(true)` is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `Date` constructor for parsing.  You're already using Moment, so just let it work.

```
moment.utc("08 Jun 2018", "DD MMM YYYY").fromNow()
```